# document.querySelectorAll(selector) inverse?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a simple way to invert

```
document.querySelectorAll(selector)
```

In other words, a way to give me all elements in document which do NOT match the selector?

Comment: What would you need that for? That would be a lot of elements, so probably a stupid approach to your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - and there's no simple way. (Not a stupid question though)

Comment: @jantimon: But that only works for *simple selectors*, not for all selectors.

Comment: as a basic fun project, I want to invert an adblock extension so that it blocks anything that's not an ad. it might not be that simple, but worth trying as I'm looking for minimum effort.

here's the actual selector:

`var selector = tag + '[' + attr + src.op + '"' + src.text + '"]';`

Comment: That's getting much more complicated, since the simple inversion of that selector would include the ad's ancestor elements - which must not be hidden. Instead, leave the selector as is and navigate the DOM to find the elements to be hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selector` is just a CSS selector, so you can use the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) selector:

`document.querySelectorAll(":not(.myClass)");`

Comment: What do you mean by "*just a CSS selector*"? It would need to be a [*simple* selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors)

Comment: I was quoting MDN: `selectors is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas`

Comment: Ah, DOM 4 would allow them; yet it seems to be not supported by any browser yet.